# Lag time in starting function from On Edit trigger - Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, lag

I have been using an On Edit trigger in a google apps script. While making this script, I have noticed that there is a short period of time between when a user finishes making an edit to the google sheet, and when the function called by the On Edit trigger begins to execute. Although this lag time is short, it is long enough for a user to quickly make additional edits to the sheet before running the function called by the On Edit trigger.

Is there any way to reduce/eliminate this lag time or to prevent the user from making any changes to the sheet while waiting for the function to begin?

I understand that the code within the function can cause a delay while the function is running, but I can resolve that issue by temporarily protecting the sheet while the function runs, and unprotecting it at the end of the function. This still leaves the issue with the lag time from the trigger because I can't protect the sheet until the function starts to run.

I can prove the existence of the lag time with the code below. The first thing this function does when called by the On Edit trigger is set the value of cell G1 to 69. If you delete the 69 in G1, you can quickly type in a different number and enter it before the function changes the value back to 69 again. The additional code and the other stuff on the sheet are just there to demonstrate what exactly I am trying to achieve with this and why. Here is a link to the related google sheet (it runs the function in the code block below when triggered by an edit): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BZB7YWguMdts-pvr7SSSEDUgSAOe023o9b_6VOhUoLw/edit?usp=sharing

```
// The goal of this function is to only allow the user to fill in column A with items from column D. The user should only be able to enter each item from column D once, but they can
// be moved around and replaced at will. 
function triggerTest() {

  //These two lines are just to quickly prove lag time. Nothing to do with the rest of this code...
  let testCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('G1');
  testCell.setValue(69);

  //These next 4 lines are just putting the values in column A and column D into arrays (getDisplayValues() returns a 2d array)
  //The cleanArray function deletes blank cells from the array and makes it a 1d array
  let databaseValues = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D2:D11').getDisplayValues();
  let cleanDatabaseValues = cleanArray(databaseValues);
  let itemsColumnValues = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A2:A11').getDisplayValues();
  let cleanItemsColumnValues = cleanArray(itemsColumnValues);

  //These for loops find all items in the column D that are not already in column A and puts them into a new array - valuesInDatabaseAndNotInItemsColumn[]
  let valuesInDatabaseAndNotInItemsColumn = cleanDatabaseValues;
  for(let i=0; i<cleanItemsColumnValues.length; i++){
    for(let j=0; j<valuesInDatabaseAndNotInItemsColumn.length; j++){
      if(valuesInDatabaseAndNotInItemsColumn[j] === cleanItemsColumnValues[i]){
        valuesInDatabaseAndNotInItemsColumn.splice(j,1);
        j--;
      }
    }
  }

  //This is the data validation for column A. It only allows values that are in Database column and NOT already in the Items column. If there is a duplicate both entries are invalid.
  //Since every cell undergoes validation, the cells that already contain entries must be allowed to keep them which is the reason for the .concat on line 44. Duplicate cells are not
  //allowed to contain their current value, hence the absence of .concat on line 41.
  for(let i=0; i<itemsColumnValues.length; i++){
    let cellIndex = (i + 2).toString();
    let cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A'+ cellIndex);
    let duplicate = false;
    let cellValidation = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation();
    for(let j=0; j<itemsColumnValues.length; j++){ //This for loop tests to see if there is a duplicate of the entry 
      if(j != i && itemsColumnValues[j][0] === itemsColumnValues[i][0]){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(duplicate === true){
      cellValidation.requireValueInList(valuesInDatabaseAndNotInItemsColumn, true).setAllowInvalid(false).build();
    }
    else{
      cellValidation.requireValueInList(valuesInDatabaseAndNotInItemsColumn.concat(itemsColumnValues[i][0]), true).setAllowInvalid(false).build();
    }
    cell.setDataValidation(cellValidation);
  }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, No`````````````````​`````````````````

Comment: I'm afraid this time lag is unavoidable. If you want to make sure the user cannot edit several cells before the `onEdit` runs, maybe you could use PropertiesService to store the cell values from last time, compare them to the new values, and if multiple changes are detected, they are reverted. Do you think something along these lines could be a valid workaround?